# C# check if there is an overload method with the specific type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, overloading, mapper

The title is maybe not that clear, I'll try to explain on an example:

I'm replacing the AutoMapper with a custom DTO mapper, and at the time need both of them to work. It there is a custom implementation use it, else fallback to AutoMapper.

The custom mapper looks something like this:

```
public static class CustomMapper
{
    public static Entity1DTO Map(Entity1 source){
        ... some mapping code ...
    }

    public static Entity2DTO Map(Entity2 source){
        ... some mapping code ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I need a way to check if the `Map` method excepts a specific type without checking for each type manually. I tried creating another overload which accepts `object` and returns `object`, but I don't know how to check if other overloads satisfy a specific type and call them.

Basically I want to make a generic wrapper method which will handle redirecting to CustomMapper or AutoMapper. Something like:

```
public static class Mapper
{
    public static T Map<T>(object source){
        return CustomMapper.Map(source) ?? AutoMapper.Map(source);
    }
}
```

So the question is how do I make a method in CustomMapper that will know if another `Map` method overload can handle the accepted type. If not return null or throw an exception, so I can fallback to AutoMapper in the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your custom mapper has simple static methods, so you can just take advantage of the usual overload resolution:

```
public static T Map<T>(Entity1 source) { ... }
public static T Map<T>(Entity2 source) { ... }
public static T Map<T>(EntityN source) { ... }

public static T Map<T>(object source) { ... }
```

The last method will be your `AutoMapper` fallback - used when there's no more direct overload.

To call this, you'd simply do `CustomMapper.Map<DTOEntityX>(whateverValue)`. If you also need this to work with the *realtime* type of `whateverValue`, you can use `dynamic` - `CustomMapper.Map<DTOEntityX>((dynamic)whateverValue)`; this will resolve the best overload at runtime.

When you're done with the transition, just remove the fallback method, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, but it is more complicated that that. The wrapper method accepts bject and when it calls the custom mapper it always goes to the last method (which then calls automapper). Additionally there is a problem with how automapper handles arrays, it treats them as T, not T[]... so basically I stick with my question. How can I call the appropriate overload method based on the type variable

Comment: @ZolaKt You can see that I didn't use the wrapper method at all - if that's not an option for you (in which case, why are you even using generics?), you could change the argument from `object` to `dynamic`, and it should work just fine.